# Get Distinct data from datatable present in webservices using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

I want to get only single row  from multiple rows with same projectname from the datatable.(Eg. if we have two rows with same projectname,the datatable should be loaded with the only one row and neglect the other one.).I have been using webservices which has the datatable.

> I want to achieve this functionality using linq.

I have pasted my code for datatable.Pls help me with working code.

```
[WebMethod]
        public DataTable Get()
        {
            int a = 0;
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = " Select PROJECTNAME,COMPANY,PROJECTSTATUS,STARTEDIN,COMPLETEDIN FROM CMPPROJECT WHERE STATUS ='" + a + "'";
            using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    dt.TableName = "CMPPROJECT";
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Can you do this on DB instead? Seems unnecessary to load both rows if only one is needed.

Comment: i have been checking with adding linq functionalities, which is mandatory for me...:-(

Comment: Even with LINQ, I guess you will modify the method you have posted? Since SQL query is hard-coded into it, why can't you make the change there?

Comment: I have been in my training session..i am very much new to linq

Comment: My option requires zero LINQ. Is it a requirement to do this only with LINQ, or are you allowed to use any other method?

Comment: No shree...its only available option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `DataView` object which has a method `ToTable` in which you can pass `true` to parameter `distinct` to select distinct rows. But this has no sense to me. I would do this directly in a select query:

```
DataTable d = new DataTable("CMPPROJECT");
d.Columns.Add("PROJECTNAME");
d.Columns.Add("COMPANY");

d.Rows.Add(1, 1);
d.Rows.Add(1, 1);
d.Rows.Add(2, 2);

d = new DataView(d).ToTable("CMPPROJECT", true, "PROJECTNAME", "COMPANY");
```

Here is `linq solution:

```
var select = (from a in d.AsEnumerable()
              select new { c1 = a["PROJECTNAME"], c2 = a["COMPANY"] }).Distinct().ToList();

d.Clear();

foreach (var item in select)
    d.Rows.Add(item.c1, item.c2);
```